# Flutter Set up Issue

Tags: flutter, macos, terminal, path

While attempting to set up Flutter on my Mac device, I've encountered quite the struggle. I had to download XCode, as well as cocoapod. To download cocoapod, I used homebrew to make things easier and had to change some paths in my terminal. However, I fear I might have messed some things up.

When I open terminal I have the message "/opt/homebrew/opt/chruby/share/chruby/chruby.sh:5: command not found: ls
chruby: unknown Ruby: ruby-3.2.2" which is not normal.
I also have: "/Users/home/.zshrc:22: permission denied: /Users/home" which I don't know what this means.

I am trying to update my paths in terminal using all sorts of terminal commands such as "vim ~/.zshrc and sudo vi ~/.zshrc" but nothing is working anymore.

How do I edit my paths in terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Did you use "sudo" beginning of the command?

If you already tried sudo. May this commands can help to you;

```
cd /Users/home/

ls -l .zshrc

chmod +rw .zshrc
```